# Convergence of a system of ODE's (replicator dynamics)

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, dynamical-systems

I have to find the points of convergence (i.e. $\lim_{t\to\infty} v^k(t)$) of the following replicator dynamics, given by a system of $4$ linear ODE's:
$$\frac{\dot{v}^k(t)}{v^k(t)}=\alpha[(Av)^k-v^TAv]\quad if\quad v^k(t)>0$$
$$\dot{v}^k(t)=0\qquad if\quad v^k(t)=0$$
given an initial $v^k(0)>0$ for $k=1,2,3,4$.

For what matters $A$ is the following matrix:
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
4 & 5 & 4 & 3\\
3 & 4 & 5 & 4\\
2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I have never studied dynamical systems, and I only know how to study those of the very simple form:
$$\dot{x}=Ax$$
via the exponential matrix of $A$. So I am clueless.

Any help would be precious, also, I would be very interested in an handy reference about this kind of problems.

Comment: Check the literature on Lotka-Volterra models. Those models have been extensively studied in ecology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In its current form, your question is very broad and it is difficult to give a specific answer. Here what I would say from first glance.

This is a non-linear system. You can write it in a standard vectorized form as follows:

$$\frac{1}{\alpha}\, \frac{dv}{dt} \, =\, \text{diag}\big(A\,v\big)\,v \, -\, (v^TA\,v)\, v$$
$$v \in \mathbb{R}^4 \, \text{ and }\, v > 0$$
where $\det(A) \neq 0$. Since you can reparametrize $\tau = \alpha\,  t$ you can work with the system, where I have relabeld $\tau$ back to $t$.

$$\frac{dv}{dt} \, =\, \text{diag}\big(A\,v\big)\,v \, -\, (v^TA\,v)\, v$$
$$v \in \mathbb{R}^4 \, \text{ and }\, v > 0$$

The first thing one could do is to find all the equilibrium points (i.e. the fixed points) of the system, which are in the domain $v > 0$. This means one needs to solve the system of cubic polynomial equations
$$\text{diag}\big(A\,v\big)\,v \, -\, (v^TA\,v)\, v \, =\, 0$$ For example, if you would like to find the equilibrium points in the interior the domain $v > 0$ we get the following system of quadratic equations
$$
\text{diag}\big(A\,v\big) \, -\, (v^TA\,v)\,I\, =\, 0
$$
Assume that $$A \, = \, \begin{bmatrix} a_1^T\\ a_2^T \\a_3^T \\ a_4^T \end{bmatrix}$$
where $a_1^T, \, a_2^T, \, a_3^T, \, a_4^T$ are the rows of the matrix $A$. Then the system of quadratic equations is
\begin{align}
& v^TA\,v \, - a_1^Tv\, =\, 0\\
& v^TA\,v \, - a_2^Tv\, =\, 0\\
& v^TA\,v \, - a_3^Tv\, =\, 0\\
& v^TA\,v \, - a_4^Tv\, =\, 0
\end{align}
If you subtract the first equation from the second, third and forth, the system simplifies to one quadratic equation and three linear homogeneous ones:
\begin{align}
& v^TA\,v \, - a_1^Tv\, =\, 0\\
& (a_1 -a_2)^Tv\, =\, 0\\
& (a_1 -a_3)^Tv\, =\, 0\\
& (a_1 -a_4)^Tv\, =\, 0
\end{align}
Solve the system of 3 linear equations of four variables
\begin{align}
& (a_1 -a_2)^Tv\, =\, 0\\
& (a_1 -a_3)^Tv\, =\, 0\\
& (a_1 -a_4)^Tv\, =\, 0
\end{align}
you can check that it is a full rank system, because $\det(A)\neq 0$, so there is a one parameter family of solutions (i.e. the solutions form a line thourgh the origin). Let us say the line is of the form
$$v \, =\, s\,u_0$$ where $u_0 \in \mathbb{R}^4$ and $s \in \mathbb{R}$.
Then plug the latter in the quadratic equation
$$v^TA\,v \, - a_1^Tv\, =\, 0$$
obtaining a quadratic equation for $s$:
$$(u_0^TA\,u_0)\,s^2 \, - (a_1^Tu_0)\,s\, =\, 0$$ and since $s \neq 0$ you get
$$s = \frac{\, (a_1^Tu_0) \,}{\,(u_0^TA\,u_0)\,}$$ Consequently, the equilibrium point in the domain $v > 0$ should be
$$v_0 \, =\, \frac{\, (a_1^Tu_0) \,}{\,(u_0^TA\,u_0)\,} \, u_0$$
The other equilibrium points you would have to find are the ones where at least one component of $v$ must be zero.

Observe that if a solution trajectory starts from a point on a coordinate 3D hyperplane, coordinate plane or coordinate line, it is entirely restricted on the same coordinate 3D hyperplane, coordinate plane or coordinate line, i.e. coordinate 3D hyperplanes, coordinate planes or coordinate lines are invariant under the flow generated by the solutions of the system of differential equations.

After you find all equilibrium points with the property $v \geq 0$, you have to linearize the system at each equilibrium points and study the eigenvalues of the linearization matrix. That will give you an idea about the local dynamics (the behaviour of the solution trajectories near the equilibrium points). After that, you would try to determine what is the stability of each equilibrium point and you would try to piece together which trajectories converges to which equilibrium point. So this is a lot of work.

I did some brief analysis and I suggest to look at the point $$e_1 = [1, 0, 0, 0]^T$$ which you can check is an equilibrium point for the system and if you linearize around it you will see that $e_1$ is an asymptotically stable node that attracts a large portion of trajectories (and further analysis might show that almost all trajectories end up there, but I have not looked into that). Consequently, many solutions will have the property $$\lim_{t \to \infty} \,v(t) \, =\, e_1$$ i.e.

$$\lim_{t \to \infty} \,v^1(t) \, =\, 1$$
$$\lim_{t \to \infty} \,v^k(t) \, =\, 0 $$
for $k = 2,3,4$.

Moreover, denote by $e = [1, 1, 1, 1]^T$. For any real number $c > 0$, denote by $S_c$ the open four dimensional filled simplex $$S_c \, =\, \big\{ v \in \mathbb{R}^4 \, : \, e^Tv < c \text{ and } v > 0 \,\big\}$$ Fix some $c < 1$. By the fact that the coordinate 3D hyperplanes, the coordinate planes and the coordinate axes are all invariant with respect to the flow of solution of the system, every solutions that starts from a point $v > 0$ has the property $v(t) > 0$ for all $t$. Hence we know that if $v \in S_c$ then the only way a solution $v(t)$ starting from the point $v$ can exit $S_c$ is through the simplex 3D face $e^Tv = c$, i.e. there should be $t^*>0$ such that $e^Tv(t^*) = c$. Let us compute the angle between the normal vector $e$ of the 3D  hyperplane $e^Tv = c$ and the direction of the vector tangent to the solution at the point of intersection $v(t^*)$.
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt} e^Tv \, =\, e^T \frac{dv}{dt} \, =\, e^T\Big(\,\text{diag}\big(A\,v\big)\,v \, -\, (v^TA\,v)\, v\,\Big)
\, =\, e^T\text{diag}\big(A\,v\big)\,v \, -\, (v^TA\,v)\, (e^Tv
)\end{align}
Since $ e^T\text{diag}\big(A\,v\big) = (A\,v)^T = v^TA^T$ the result is
$$\frac{d}{dt} e^Tv \, =\, e^T \frac{dv}{dt} \, =\,  (v^TA^T\,v) \, -\, (v^TA\,v)\, (e^Tv) =\,  (v^TA\,v) \, -\, (v^TA\,v)\, (e^Tv) \,= \, (v^TA\,v) \big(\,1\, -\, e^Tv \,\big)$$ and because $e^Tv = c$ and $v^TA\,v > 0$ for $v > 0$
$$\frac{d}{dt} e^Tv \, =\, e^T \frac{dv}{dt} \,= \, (v^TA\,v) \big(\,1\, -\, c\,\big)$$
This allows us to see that when $c < 1$, then $\frac{d}{dt} e^Tv \, =\, e^T \frac{dv}{dt} > 0$ which means that the trajectories near by the origin, always leave the simplices $S_c$, i.e. trajectories that start near the origin, do not stay near the origin, but diverge from it. However, as soon as $c > 1$, then $\frac{d}{dt} e^Tv \, =\, e^T \frac{dv}{dt} < 0$ which means that trajectories that start inside $S_c$ always stay there. So almost all trajectories inside $v>0$ are always trapped inside the domain $S_{c_2} \setminus S_{c_1}$ between any pair of nested simplexes $S_{c_1} \subset S_{c_2}$ for any  $c_1 < 1 < c_2$. So the point $e_1$ seems to be a major attracting equilibrium point with very large basin of attraction.

If one wants a bit more focused analysis, one can observe that when $c=1$, the equality
$$\frac{d}{dt} e^Tv \, =\, e^T \frac{dv}{dt}  \, = \,  (v^TA\,v) \big(\,1\, -\, 1\,\big) \, =\, 0$$ which means that the compact 3D simplex $$s_{1} \, =\, \big\{\,v \in \mathbb{R}^4 \, : \, e^Tv = 1 \, \text{ and } \, v > 0 \,\big\}$$ which is a 3D boundary face of the 4D simplex $S_1$ is invariant with respect to the flow of solutions of the system of differential equations. Which means that for any $v \in s_1$ the whole solution trajectory $v(t)$ that starts from $v$ lies entirely in $s_1$. On top of that, one can check (just like before) that all points $e_2 = [0,1,0,0]^T, \, e_3 = [0,0,1,0]^T, \, e_4 = [0,0,0,1]^T, \,$ are equilibrium stationary points of the system.

One thing that could be applied here is to look at a continuous family of trapping subsimplexes $\{s_c \, : \, c\}$ of $s_1$. For example, consider the vector $e = e_1 + e_2 + e_3 + e_4 = [1,1,1,1]^T$. Then $\frac{1}{3}\,e$ is the vector pointing to the centroid of the simplex $s_1$. Then the vector $\frac{1}{3}\,e \, -\, e_1$ is a vector lying in the simplex $s_1$.
For a number $c \geq 0$ define the hyperplane
$$\Big(\frac{1}{3}\,e \, -\, e_1\Big)^T(v-e_1) \,=\, c$$ which can be rewritten as
$$\Big(\frac{1}{3}\,e \, -\, e_1\Big)^Tv \,=\, c  - \frac{2}{3}$$
and with its help, define the 3D simplex inside the 3D simplex $s_1$
$$s_c \, =\, \Big\{\,v \in s_1 \,:\, \Big(\frac{1}{3}\,e \, -\, e_1\Big)^Tv < c - \frac{2}{3}\,\Big\}$$
which can be reformulated as
$$
s_c \, =\, \Big\{\,v \in \mathbb{R}^4 \,:\, e^Tv = 1 \,\text{ and }\, \Big(\frac{1}{3}\,e \, -\, e_1\Big)^Tv = c - \frac{2}{3}\,\text{ and }\, 
 v > 0\,\Big\}$$
Just like before, a trajectory that starts in $s_c$ can leave $s_c$ only through the face defined by the hyperplane $$\Big(\frac{1}{3}\,e \, -\, e_1\Big)^Tv = c - \frac{2}{3}$$ So, a trajectory $v(t)$ that starts in $s_c$ at time $t=0$, would leave $s_c$ through that hyperplane at time $t=t^*$ only when at time $t=t^*$ the said trajectory satisfies the hyperplane equation $$\Big(\frac{1}{3}\,e \, -\, e_1\Big)^Tv(t^*) \,=\, c -\frac{2}{3}$$ and at the same time its velocity satisfies
$$\frac{d}{dt} \, \left(\Big(\frac{1}{3}\,e \, -\, e_1\Big)^Tv(t) \right){\Big|_{t=t^*}} \, =\, \Big(\frac{1}{3}\,e \, -\, e_1\Big)^T\frac{dv}{dt}(t^*) > 0$$ However, for those $v \in s_1$ for which
$$
\Big(\frac{1}{3}\,e \, -\, e_1\Big)^T\frac{dv}{dt} \, =\, 
\Big(\frac{1}{3}\,e \, -\, e_1\Big)^T \Big( \text{diag}(A\,v) - (v^TA\,v)I \Big)\,v \, < \, 0
$$  no trajectory can escape through point $v$. Because from before
$$e^T \Big( \text{diag}(A\,v) - (v^TA\,v)I \Big)\,v \, = \, 0$$
the latter inequality simplifies to
$$ e_1^T\Big( \text{diag}(A\,v)\,v - (v^TA\,v)\,v \Big)  > 0$$
and can be even further simplified to
$$(e_1^T A\,v)\,(e_1^T v) - (v^TA\,v)\,(e_1^T v) \, =\, 
\Big(\,(e_1^T A\,v) - (v^TA\,v)\,\Big)\,(e_1^T v)  > 0$$
Observe that $e_1^Tv = v_1 > 0$ since $v \in s_1$, which allows us to rewrite the inequality as
$$(e_1^T A\,v) - (v^TA\,v) > 0$$
The equation $$(v^TA\,v) - (e_1^T A\,v) = 0$$ defines a quadratic 3D hypersurface in $\mathbb{R}^4$ and when intersected with the 3D simplex $s_1$ it defines a portion of a 2D quadratic surface in $s_1$.
Thus, for the equilibrium point $e_1$, one can define the subset of $s_1$
\begin{align}
D \, &= \,\Big\{\,v \in s_1\,:\,  (v^TA\,v) - (e^T_1A\,v) <  0 \,\Big\}\\
&= \, \Big\{\,v \in \mathbb{R}^4\,:\, (v^TA\,v) - (e^T_1A\,v) <  0  \, \text{ and }\, e^Tv = 1 \, \text{ and }\, v > 0\,\Big\}
\end{align}

which defines an open subdomain $D$ of $s_1$ with the property that for any solution $v(t)$ that starts from a point inside $D$
$$\lim_{t \to \infty} \, v(t) \, =\, e_1$$

Comment: Thanks for the very informative answer! Actually,  I am mostly interested in the case where the system describes an evolutionary game, hence trajectories start and are confined to the unit simplex. Indeed, $[1,0,0,0]$ is the unique Nash equilibrium of the symmetric game described by $A$. Hence, what I have to prove is that any trajectory starting in the interior of the unit simplex converges $[1,0,0,0]$, so that it is globally attractive for the interior of the unit simplex.

Comment: I asked the question in the completely general context, to see if some general result could dispense me from the phase portrait analysis. But apparently, this is not the case! Then, it seems to me that by direct inspection one sees that $\dot{v}^1(t)\geq 0$, for any $t$, with equality only if $v^{t}=e_1$. Is this sufficient to conclude?

Comment: @FrancescoBilotta I do not think simply showing that $\frac{dv^1}{dt}(t) \geq 0$ is enough, as it just shows that $v^1(t)$ is monotonously increasing function, starting from  $0 < v^1(0) < 1$ and monotonously growing, while the rest of the components $v^i(t)$ for $i=2,3,4$, bound by the conservation property $v^1(t) + v^2(t) + v^3(t) + v^4(t)  = 1$, are expected to behave in way that satisfies the latter identity. However, one needs something more in order to show that actually $\lim_{t \to \infty} v^1(t) = 1$, which will force the rest of the components to go to zero.

Comment: @FrancescoBilotta Actually, one can see that $\dot v^1(t)<0$ for states $v$ close to $e_4=[0,0,0,1]^T$.

Comment: @FrancescoBilotta I added some more analysis to my answer which may allow you to find an open domain of points whose solution trajectories converge to $e_1$. Although this domain may not describe the whole basin of attraction of $e_1$, but it may capture a large portion of it.

Answer (score 2):

This question can be answered using Theorem 7.2.1(b) in the chapter on replicator dynamics in the book of Hofbauer and Sigmund, *Evolutionary Games and Population Dynamics*.  For solutions taking values in the unit simplex in $\mathbb{R}^4$, this result says that if the solution converges, the limit must be a Nash equilibrium.  Since you know $e_1=[1,0,0,0]^T$ is the unique Nash equilibrium, it is the only possible limit.

The conclusion holds for any solution $v(t)$ in the positive orthant of $\mathbb{R}^4$, as well, for the following reasons: First,  as Futurologist showed, with $e=[1,1,1,1]^T$ one computes that $s(t)=e^Tv(t)=\sum_k v^k(t)$ satisfies
$$
\dot s(t) = (v^TAv)(1-s(t)).
$$
Since  every entry of the matrix $A$ is $1$ or larger, one has $(Av)^k>s$ for all $k$, whence $v^TAv> s^2$.  Hence $s(t)$ is strictly increasing if it is less than $1$, decreasing if greater.

If we assume $\hat v = \lim_{t\to\infty}v(t)$ exists, then from the ODEs it follows $\lim_{t\to\infty} \dot v^k(t)$ exists for each $k$, and these limits must be zero (by a mean-value-theorem argument).   For a similar reason, using the equation for $\dot s(t)$ it follows $e^T\hat v=\lim_{t\to\infty}s(t)=1$. Hence $\hat v$ is a rest point and lies in the closed unit simplex.

If $\hat v$ is *not* a Nash equilibrium, it follows by direct negation of the definition of such that $$
w^T A\hat v > \hat v^T A \hat v
$$
for some $w$ in the unit simplex.  The left-hand side is a weighted average of components $(A\hat v)^k$, so for some particular component we have $(A\hat v)^k > \hat v^T A \hat v$. For this component, by continuity there is a constant $\delta>0$ such that $(Av)^k-v^TAv>\delta$ for all $v$ in some neighborhood of $\hat v$.  Then the ODE's imply
$$
\frac{\dot v^k(t)}{v^k(t)} = \frac{d}{dt}\log v^k(t) \ge \alpha\delta  >0
$$
for all sufficiently large $t$.  This leads to a contradiction with the assumption that $v^k(t)\to \hat v_k \in [0,1]$.

One should note that this argument does not prove that the Nash equilibrium $e_1$ globally attracts solutions in the positive orthant. It remains possible that some kind of non-convergent behavior persists.  Complicated dynamic behavior is known to be possible in replicator dynamics in general, though perhaps it can be ruled out in this example if, say, a suitable Lyapunov function can be found.

(By the way, I was able to check that $e_1$ is indeed the only Nash equilibrium, but not very easily---if you can say how you know this, please do.)

Comment: thanks! I did look at Theorem 7.2.1(b) in the chapter on replicator dynamics in the book of Hofbauer and Sigmund, Evolutionary Games and Population Dynamics. The results says that if a point is the limit point of an orbit in $int S_n$, the limit must be a Nash equilibrium. So are you telling me it is _the orbit_ which must entirely lie in $int S_n$ (granted by interior initial condition) and not necessarily the limit point ? Gosh,  I thought they were referring to the limit point and lost a lot of time.

Comment: To check that $e_1$ is the only Nash equilibrium, you can simply see that it is the _unique_ action profile surviving _iterated deletion of dominated actions_ (in epistemic terms, the obly rationalizable action profile). Actually, I was also refered to a paper of Hofbauer  et al. were they prove that iterated deletion of dominated actions is supported by imitation dynamics https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4397099/transfinite-limit-of-an-orbit-of-a-dynamical-system-and-rationalizability-of-sym coherently with the above result.

Comment: Indeed it is the orbit that is required to lie in int $S_n$, not the limit point.  And thanks, I see now that iterated deletion works easily - I missed that before.

Comment: Thanks, now to you, I was missing an important result!